# Making a fullscreen slideshow. Css width Issues

Tags: css

Ok so here's the deal.
I've decided that I want to not use a jquery plugin for this as I want to learn and keep things as clean as possible.

I'm trying to create a fullscreen horizontal slideshow.

I have a container div that's 100% width & height.

I have a sub-container with a width of say 999%

within that sub-container I have images floating left, but here's the problem:
I want each image to be the width of the main container div or 100% and not the sub-container. I'm making it so the images resize proportionately depending on browser size so I can't give it a specific px size.

Any idea how I can go about this? I've already tried using jquery on window resize to get and set the image div size to the document size but for some reason it does not work. As soon as I resize the window the image width jumps over 100% of the document width.

Edit: As requested here's an example of code.
Basically, I want to make the .imgBlock widths always the main container's width. I cannot use 100% as the width because it's in a subcontainer that will have a variable width.

```
#mainContainer {
float:left;
width:100%; 
height:100px; 
position:relative; 
background:#000;        
}

#subContainer {
width:auto; 
height:100%;
background:#f00;
float:left;   
}

.imgBlock {
float:left; 
height:100%; 
border:1px solid #fff;    
}

<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="subContainer">
    <li class="imgBlock"><h1>IMAGE</h1></li>
    <li class="imgBlock"><h1>IMAGE</h1></li>
    <li class="imgBlock"><h1>IMAGE</h1></li>
    <li class="imgBlock"><h1>IMAGE</h1></li>
    <li class="imgBlock"><h1>IMAGE</h1></li>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Markup, CSS, jQuery, Fiddle, will be better if you share something from these

Comment: Please post you CSS/HTML/JS. You may create working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Basic Internet users do not prefer to resize window :) So, you can start with jquery code for getting window/document width and height. And if you really need to support resize, use .resize() or .change().

Answer (score 0):

Ok the resize() jquery function worked. The issue seemed to have come about due to the main container not being overflow:hidden.

```
var docuW = $(document).width();
$(".imgBlock").css({'width': docuW });

$(window).resize(function() {
    docuW = $(document).width();
    $(".imgBlock").css({'width': docuW });  
});
```